# Interacting with popup scrollbar

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scroll down the popup window here: (note you'll need to click any food item on the page to bring up the popup in question)

https://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-mcdonalds-claphamjunction/menu

I've tried to scroll down this popup using the below code, first identifying the popup scrollbar using its css selector and then sending arrow down keys to it.

```
popup = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4) > div.c-megaModal.MegaModal_c-megaModal_3w2Fg.u-overlay.c-itemSelector.c-modal--popUp--belowMid.is-fullHeight")
popup.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I managed to scroll down fine using FireFox but I can't get it to work on Chrome (need to use Chrome for other reasons).

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

I tried the following but it's not scrolling (no error message appears it just passes through the code without scrolling).

```
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
        for _ in range(8):
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'MegaModal_c-megaModal-document--scrollable')]")))
            browser.execute_script(
                "document.querySelector('div[class*=MegaModal_c-megaModal-document--scrollable]').scrollDown += 250")
```

Comment: Unfortunately we face a _`What happened?
This request was blocked by the security rules
Your IP: w.x.y.z
Proxy IP: a.b.c.d (ID 105544-900)
Incident ID: 1122000560206975379-103202147123456789`_

Comment: Ah yeah you might need a VPN to access outside of the UK

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using a wrong locator
2. This element is not directly interactable by user. This is why you can't send keys to it with Selenium.
   Instead of sending arrow keys to that element you can scroll it with JavaScript executor.
   Please try this

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'MegaModal_c-megaModal-document--scrollable')]")))
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('div[class*=MegaModal_c-megaModal-document--scrollable]').scrollDown += 250")
```

In order to use explicit conditions as above you will need these imports

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And to initialize wait object

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

Comment: I've tried the above code but I get the same error message, It appears finding the element isn't the problem as it's located immediately and then the same error as above appears. If I'm using the wrong locator I'm not sure what the right one is?

Comment: I see. You can't scroll it with sending arrow keys however you can do it with JavaScript scrolling. Please see the updated answer

Comment: That didn't seem to have any effect. I initially tried it on it's own and then put it in a loop, just to check it definitely wasn't scrolling. I've edited the above question to show how I put it in. Again it seems like the element is located but then the scrolling action doesn't work

Comment: I've tried to use ```browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2500)", "")``` but it just scrolled the window behind the popup. Is there a way I can switch to scrolling the popup instead?